# showing undefined when trying to access the property from the collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to fetch the email from the collection soo that I compare it with user input email but somehow it's showing undefined when I try to access it using dot property. Code below

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const userSchema = new Schema({});
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema, 'adminUsers');


exports.login = (req, res, next) => {

    const email = req.body.email
    const password = req.body.password

    User.find({email: email})
    .then(resp => {
        console.log(resp.email)
    })
}
```

Comment: Make sure ‘req.body.email’ actually has a value

Comment: console.log (req.body) that returns?

Comment: req.body has the valid content in it.req.body returns the object passed as a body

Comment: User.find({})
    .then(resp => {
        console.log(resp)
    })
can i know the output of the code

Comment: it shows the following :

[
  {
    _id: 5eba97962672ad13305f700b,
    email: 'sagaryc111@gmail.com',
    password: 'gogetadmingamecsgo'
  },
  {
    _id: 5eba97a72672ad13305f700c,
    email: 'ajaybendre@credenceanalytics.com',
    password: 'gogetadmingamecoc'
  }
] @adhinarayan

Comment: ik here its an array but i tried it using foreacach and map too.

Comment: Try ```User.findone({ email })``` then ```console.log(resp)```

Comment: did you use bodyParser? If you dont use bodyParser req.body will not be taken in a proper format

Comment: it's showing proper object @zS1L3NT

Comment: yes ive properly used it. It the problem related to fetching improper data form collection.@adhinarayan

Comment: @velocityCSGO : Try this :: `User.findOne({email: email}).lean().exec(resp => {
        console.log(resp.email)
    })`

Comment: @velocityCSGO why is your user schema {}? and before using lean go through the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html)